# Not Receiving Alert for Triggered Send Queue

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, automationstudio, triggered-send, activities

I'm trying to configure Alert for TS Queue based on @Gortonington instruction https://gortonington.com/alert-for-your-triggered-send-queue-limits-in-sfmc/ but I'm not receiving alert on my email. Could anyone tell me what I did wrong?

I Automation as a Script Activity and place it in twice in two different steps.

My script:

```
<script runat=server>
Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");
    
var mid = '7310100';
var dev = 0;
var allTriggers = 0;

var alertEmailAddress = 'n.kXXX@gmail.com';
var alertSubKey = 'n.kXXX@gmail.com';
var now = new Date();
var start = now.getTime();
var timeOut = 1680000; //28 minutes
//60000 milliseconds in a minute

if (allTriggers) {
  var tsdArray = getTSDKeys(mid);
  var length = tsdArray.Results.length;
} else {
  var tsdArray = ["TX_pl-pl_DoubleOptIn"]
  var length = tsdArray.length;
  var maxQueueArray = [0]; //Enter max queue here. Can make an array as well, if different maxes per TSD
}

if (!maxQueueArray || maxQueueArray.length == 0) {
  var maxQueueDefault = 0; //Default for if not using maxQueueArray
}

if (dev) {
  timeOut = 10000;
  maxQueueArray = [0];
  maxQueueDefault = 0;
}

var alertArray = []
var queueAlertArray = []

do {

  var failures = 0;

  for (i=0; i < length; i++) {
    if(allTriggers) {
      var customerKey = tsdArray.Results[i].CustomerKey
    } else {
      var customerKey = tsdArray[i]
    }
    var queued = getTSDQueue(customerKey);
    var alreadyFail = Stringify(alertArray).indexOf(customerKey);
    dev ? Write('<hr><br>') : '';
    dev ? Write('CustomerKey: ' + customerKey + '<br>') : '';
    dev ? Write('Queue: ' + queued + '<br>') : '';
    dev ? Write('RunTime: ' + (new Date().getTime() - start) + '<br>') : '';

    var queueArrLength = maxQueueArray.length;

    // changes maxQueue to array value if exist and equal to i
    if (maxQueueArray.length > 0 && maxQueueArray.length <= i) {
      var maxQueue = maxQueueArray[i];
    } else {
      var maxQueue = maxQueueDefault;
    }

    if (queued > maxQueue) {
      
      if (alreadyFail < 1) {
        dev ? Write('<span style="color:red; font-weight:bold;">Queue Failure</span><br>') : '';
        alertArray.push(customerKey)
        queueAlertArray.push(queued)
        failures += 1
      }
    }
  }

  dev ? Write('<br>FAILURES: ' + failures + '<br><br><br>') : '';

  if (failures > 0) {
    var alertStr = Stringify(alertArray).replace('[','').replace(']','');
    var queueAlertStr = Stringify(queueAlertArray).replace('[','').replace(']','');
    var alertTrigger = sendTSDAlert(alertStr,queueAlertStr,alertEmailAddress,alertSubKey)
    dev ? Write('<br>' + Stringify(alertTrigger) + '<br>') : '';
  }

} while((new Date().getTime() - start) < timeOut)
    


/************************* FUNCTION LIST ************************/

function getTSDKeys(mid) {
  var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();

  /* Set ClientID */
  if (mid) {
    prox.setClientId({ "ID": 7310100 }); //Impersonates the BU
  }

  var cols = ["CustomerKey", "TriggeredSendStatus"];
  var res = prox.retrieve("TriggeredSendDefinition", cols, filter);

  var results = res
   
  return results;
}

function getTSDQueue(customerKey) {

  var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
  
  /* Set ClientID */
  if (mid) {
    prox.setClientId({ "ID": 7310100 }); //Impersonates the BU
  }


  var cols = ["CustomerKey","Queued"];
  var filter = {
      Property: "CustomerKey",
      SimpleOperator: "Equals",
      Value: customerKey
  };
  var res = prox.retrieve("TriggeredSendSummary", cols, filter);

  var queue = res.Results[0].Queued

  return queue;
}
    
function sendTSDAlert(alertStr,queueAlertStr,emailAddress,subKey) {
  var proxy = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
  var customerKey = "TX_pl-pl_DoubleOptIn";
  var name = "TX_pl-pl_DoubleOptIn";

  var ts= {
         TriggeredSendDefinition: {CustomerKey: customerKey, Name: name}
         ,Subscribers: [ {
                EmailAddress: emailAddress
              , SubscriberKey: subKey
              , Attributes: [
                  {
                   Name: 'tsdList',
                    Value: alertStr
                 },
                 {
                  Name: 'tsdQueue',
                  Value: queueAlertStr
                 }
              ]
          }]

      };

  var res = proxy.createItem("TriggeredSend", ts);

  return res;
}

</script>
```

Inside the email in body part I added this:

```
%%[ set @tsdList = AttributeValue("tsdList") set @tsdQueue = AttributeValue("tsdQueue") set @tsdListRows = BuildRowsetFromString(@tsdList,",") set @tsdQueueRows = BuildRowsetFromString(@tsdQueue,",") ]%% The following Triggers have exceed queue limits:
%%[FOR @i=1 TO Rowcount(@tsdListRows) DO SET @RowList = Row(@tsdListRows,@i) SET @RowQueue = Row(@tsdQueueRows,@i) if @i > 1 THEN ]%%
%%[ endif ]%%
Trigger CustomerKey: %%=Substring(TRIM(Field(@RowList,1)),2,SUBTRACT(Length(TRIM(Field(@RowList,1))),2))=%%
Trigger Queue Count: %%=Field(@RowQueue,1)=%%

%%[ NEXT @i ]%%
```

My trigger Send that I'm testing now has 3 records in Queue.

I would be gratful for any suggestions what I should change in order to receive alert.